# Will running related questions from F&N be migrated to Sports?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have asked some running related questions on Fitness&Nutrition. How can I migrate them to Sports (probably only when the public beta starts)?

Comment: Good point.  Also, will Running questions be 'excluded' from Fitness and Nutrition?  Or all Sports questions?

Comment: Are you asking about migrating only *your* running questions (as stated in your question body) or *all* running questions (as your title suggests and @geoffc brings up) from Fitness?

Answer (score 6):

No.

Running is on topic on both sites and should remain as such. However running questions here should be directed towards competitive running (I don't care how F&N chooses to define their scope on running questions or whether there is overlap). However this is not the place for recreational running.

Comment: What about a question that could just as easily apply to competitive running or recreational running? Also, is this a precedent that says only competitive sports questions are allowed here, and that recreational sporting would not? Say my coworkers go play some ultimate frisbee Wednesdays - would questions on strategy there not be accepted?

Comment: How do you define the difference between competitive and recreational? See http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/30/38 This requirement is not mentioned on the FAQ!

Comment: @TonnyMadsen the FAQ argument is a poor one on day 1 of a beta. our FAQ is just the standard SE boiler plate. Much more important would be to decide how the communities in both places feel and determine scope from there.

Comment: @corsiKa good question. Ultimate is still competitive isn't it? Running is a tough one, but purpose is important here. For the most part running questions are and should remain on topic here.

Comment: The reason, I write this is because your answer seems very clean cut and definitive and something that has been decided on a long time ago :-) And thus something that will be in the FAQ very early :-)

Comment: @TonnyMadsen nothing has been decided yet. My answer is clean cut and definitive because my opinion is such. I don't have any authority here.

Comment: Just been looking at the original proposal and I cannot find anything about this... Do you have a reference? I would personally prefer a definition where we talk about participation or not.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen this is the best i can find http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/where-does-running-proposal-belong-sports-or-fitnessnutrition. This is meta if you don't like my proposal please feel free to down vote it.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen On meta, up/down votes mean "I agree" or "I disagree". Ignore the help text on the actual buttons about useful and clear and such. There's no rep penalty and honestly, we're all adults here, there's no hard feelings. (At least, on the general case, there aren't. I'm sure there's exceptions...)

Comment: yes please up or down vote proposals on meta in order to voice agreement or disagreement. No one will cry about a ton of downvotes (and if they do tell them to suck it up (there's no crying in Sports.SE :))

Comment: @wax really? There's no cr... seriously? http://questionablecontent.net/comics/1410.png :-)

Comment: @corsiKa :'( :P

Answer (score 4):

A moderator will have to migrate the questions from Fitness to Sports. You currently have [two questions on Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/95/pesche?tab=questions) (both related to running), but the ["running" tag](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running) is also the largest tag on Fitness with 179 questions total.

There isn't a need to migrate any questions especially when Sports is (currently) in private beta and the scope and faq haven't been fully determined yet. As it stands right now, all the running questions are on-topic for Fitness.