# How does Fitness and Nutrition, with Sports related questions, interact?

Tags: discussion, scope, se-sites

What are the boundaries to define if a question belongs on Sports or F&N?

Looks like we may need some collaboration cross sites to decide how best to partition the questions?

Comment: Merge with http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1/will-running-related-questions-from-fn-be-migrated-to-sports as "Sport and F&N co-existence"?

Comment: The other question was running specific. This is the general case of all sports stuff.

Comment: That's true. However, will answering your question answer the other one too?

Comment: @DmitrySelitskiy: I suppose so.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the boundaries to define if a question belongs on Sports or F&N?

The following two questions (from the first few days of beta) clarify the boundaries:

[Will running related questions from F&N be migrated to Sports?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1)

> running questions here should be directed towards competitive running (I don't care how F&N chooses to define their scope on running questions or whether there is overlap). However this is not the place for recreational running.

[Competitive or Recreational Running](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30)

> we should only host questions about running (or any other recreational sport) that are specifically about the competitive aspect of the sport.

And over four years after the questions above were addressed, it was fortified in the question below:

[Why has a question on swimming technique been closed as off-topic?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/641)

> Obviously there is overlap between the two sites, so should be done is look at the intent of the question.
>
> ...
>
> If the
>   intent is to improve the competitive aspect, then it's probably a
>   better fit here. If the intent is to improve in general, then probably
>   a better fit on fitness.

---

> Looks like we may need some collaboration cross sites to decide how best to partition the questions

The most recent question referenced above was answered by two moderators of Fitness SE. They agree with the consensus that questions about an activity is on-topic on Sports SE **if** it is about a competitive aspect. Otherwise, it is most likely on-topic at Fitness SE (given it fits within their scope).