# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

*One of the [7 essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)*

Straight-forward but difficult and very important question. 
Let's work together on defining this new site especially considering that we have a closely related [Fitness & Nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) site on the network (as raised in [another meta question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-does-fitness-and-nutrition-with-sports-related-questions-interact))

A great place to start is the [definition of the site on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports). Also have a look at the [F&N's FAQ](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) and especially the questions they exclude. Some, like "Rules of Sports" is a great fit for us and an illustration that we should be able to co-exist with F&N.

Let's get started in an answer and modify it based on the community input.

Answer (score 5):

I think the "Rules of Sports" is good - as well as Training Tips, technical tips (form and technique play an important role in many sports) - questions about equipment also.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the FAQ-building process, but it seems to me there should be a place where we can collaboratively edit the faq. Maybe my rep is just too low. But maybe we could make this thread a community wiki so that we can discuss and edit.

Currently the faq basically contains:

> Sports - Stack Exchange is for participants in team and individual
>   sport activities.

Per the previous answers and comments I'd suggest a starter along the lines of:

> Sports - Stack Exchange is for participants in team and individual
>   sport activities as well as fans thereof. You can ask questions about
>   rules, tactics, equipment, locations, as well as famous people connected to sports.
>   This site is both for spectators, the recreational as well as professional athletes.

..someone has to start..

Comment: ♦ moderators can edit that sentence (and only that sentence), just so everyone's clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can ask "what should our faq contain" any more than you can ask "how can we achieve world peace"?

We start with a boilerplate faq, and make amendments to it as issues arise. Ironically, the questions that we must continually ask ourselves as we go through the beta do not directly translate to questions that are suitable for the format.

In effect, there is no answer to this question without other issues first being taken care of, and is comprised entirely of the answers to those other issues.

Answer (score -4):

We should continue the initial charter of 'for participants in team and individual sport activities', and should therefore clarify that it is about sport participation, rules, and training for the sport, not straight fandom such as statistics questions, etc. Participation and training in teams or targeting for competition within actual leagues might be another differentiating aspect from F&N.

Comment: disagree strongly. The original sports proposal was for fandom as much as participants, this should be a place for that as well.