# Types of Equipment related Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

We are beginning to get closer to a usable definition of the types of sports we want to cover on the site (AFAIKS). But what about questions on equipment?

From [What should our FAQ contain?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/38) questions on equipment in general seems to be on topic.

What about question on the various pro et con for equipment for a particular use? E.g.

- the different types of water-belts for long distance running?
- add-on spikes when running in the winter?
- running apps for mobile devices versus dedicated watches?

Yet we don't want the obvious shopping questions - e.g. "which ... should I buy".

How do we distinguish general equipment questions from shopping questions - that seems a little fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as equipment goes we walk a fine line between good expert Q&A on equipment and "shopping questions." Here are the guidelines I would enforce

- A question asking "What brand should I buy of X" is off topic. These kinds of things will age rapidly and will be rather useless long term.
- A question asking "Differentiate equipment X from Equipment Y" where X and Y are two distinct types of equipment (putter vs driver, barbell vs dumbbell etc) should be constructive.
- A question asking for the uses of different types of equipment and what circumstances they are good for is constructive.
- A question asking "What is the right type of X for me" is usually not constructive unless there is enough detail and then it may still be too localized.
- A question asking "how do I use equipment of type X" is constructive.

These are my opinions on how equipment questions should be asked.

Comment: So when you ask a question which type you should consider buying it is wrong, but when you ask a question which type you should use it is good?? I agree with the brand part, but aspects to watch for buying should be oke. Then again should that not be in fitness & nutrition where do you draw the line?

Comment: @scubaFLY good question. I'm differentiating here between brand and equipment type. (speedo vs type of goggle for swimming perhaps). Some questions should go to fitness, but others are quite all right here. (dumbbell vs barbell is likely a fitness question, but it was a good example)

Comment: I saw an other comment of you @waxeagle and I think your point of sport being more professional and fitness more self related sports is great to define a better line between the 2.

Comment: @scubaFLY we need to be clear that [fitness.se] also covers professional participation quite clearly. Its on topic in both places.

Comment: I think the FAQ should be updated to start with, It's very unclear what can and cannot be posted in sports. Personally I would like the 2 to be merged but thats not up to me ;)

Comment: @scubaFLY our FAQ really can't be updated until we have our own site mods (we will get some in a couple of weeks). SE employees could update it, but its generally left until mods are appointed.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can easily and safely be copied from other sites FAQ: [F&N](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) for instance:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> - gear and gadgets used during exercise
>
> and it's not on...
>
> - a purchase recommendation

I think that in time it will be clear to us (and the rest).