# Are shooting sports on topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions about shooting sports on topic here? If not, can you answer the same question about the Outdoors site?

Answer (score 4):

As with other activities which can be done either competitively or recreationally, shooting sports are on-topic here **if the question is about the competitive aspect of the sport** - see [here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/641/why-has-a-question-on-swimming-technique-been-closed-as-off-topic) for the previous meta discussion on this with regards to swimming (or [here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/competitive-or-recreational-running) for an older discussion on running). For example, "how is a clay pigeon tournament scored?" is on-topic, but "how should I flush grouse?" Is off-topic and best asked at The Great Outdoors.

Comment: I will add that outdoors.SE [has shooting tag](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting) - although at the moment only with 10 questions, 2 of them [closed](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bshooting%5D+closed%3A1). And on this site, there are at the moment 9 questions tagged ([tag:shooting]) (none of them closed). Browsing through older questions might although help with rough idea what can be asked. (Although SE sites evolve, especially while they are in beta.)