# Can someone Create a Yoga Tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Can someone create a Yoga Tag, there are yoga sport competitions. I don't have enough points to create this tag.

Thanks,

Question Reference:
[What is this bent knee handstand position called in Yoga or Gymnastics?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/what-is-this-bent-knee-handstand-position-called-in-yoga-or-gymnastics?noredirect=1#comment35753_26207)

Competitions:

https://www.usayoga.org/champions

https://www.usayoga.org/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_yoga

Comment: Are there any questions you wish to ask or that already exist that need this tag? In general, we do not create tags prior to there being questions about a subject - in fact, there's no way to create a tag without there being a question - so if there are questions already, please add them to your question for the reference of those users who are able to create tags.

Comment: hi @Catija yes, please see this question https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/what-is-this-bent-knee-handstand-position-called-in-yoga-or-gymnastics?noredirect=1#comment35753_26207

Comment: Could you give some links to the global yoga competitive governing body, some links to recent "match" reports or similar? Just trying to gauge if "yoga sport" fits into our definition of competitive sport.

Comment: hi @PhilipKendall please see new links in question https://www.usayoga.org/champions,  anyways even if there is no competition, its still a sport like any physical fitness, just like golf or badmington, etc

Comment: @PhilipKendall https://www.iysf.org/ should fit in.

Comment: @mattsmith5 For the scope of Sports SE, it _does_ matter as we are specifically about _competitive_ sports, while non-competitive activities have a happy home on [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com); see [this meta question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/641/why-has-a-question-on-swimming-technique-been-closed-as-off-topic) for the earlier community consensus on how we try to distinguish the two. That said, the things you and dly have linked to are certainly competitive so we're good here. Thanks both.

Answer (score 3):

Tag now created with excerpt and very brief description.