# Is "Is there a recommended running technique if you're overweight?" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

[Is there a recommended running technique if you're overweight?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/554/is-there-a-recommended-running-technique-if-youre-overweight)

Isn't this a F&N question?  Or is this a proof of concept for merging the two per the meta discussion?  I almost flagged it before I noticed it was posted by a mod.

Based on this answer:  https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4/183 it seems like recreational running is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll talk with Ivo to see if he feels it match on F&N..

Comment: F&N wants it... I'll try to migrate it :-)

Comment: If you're able to migrate it let me know how that's done - I'd like to be educated on the process.

Comment: It turns out to be real easy. Just close the question as "Off topic" and specify "belongs to...". That's it..

Comment: great, thanks. I'm coming to understand the difference between Sports.SE and Fitness.SE better now too.

Answer (score 2):

This was my question.

Now that you brought it up - it looks like there is a question on F&N that would be suitable to merge mine with: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/115

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I can see) to merge a question from one site with another. If there is, please let me know (I'm new to the SE sites and being a mod). Otherwise, what would the correct action to take on the question now? Close it?

Comment: That's something we would do on our end after the migration. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is “Is there a recommended running technique if you're overweight?” on-topic?

As stated elsewhere on meta<sub>[(1)](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4)[(2)](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35)</sub>, recreational running is off-topic. We allow running questions if they are "specifically about the competitive aspect of the sport.<sub>[(1)](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4)</sub>" Running technique for the overweight isn't explicitly nor specifically about the competitive aspect of running.

In any case, this type of question is better suited for Fitness SE.